# Data from QTcpSocket dissapear when reading from socket is finished (altough they reach the socket)

Tags: c++, qt, networking, tcp

I'm writing a simple client-server app in Qt and have a problem with reading data on client side. Data get to the client, but I can't extract them to the variables in a class, they seem to be destroyed.

The code looks like this:

Receiver:

```
void ClientTcpHelper::UnpackData(){

stream=new QDataStream (&this->socket);
stream->startTransaction();
*stream>>P1_X>> P1_Y>>P2_X>> P2_Y>>Ghost1_X>>Ghost1_Y>>Ghost2_X>>Ghost2_Y>> Ghost3_X>>Ghost3_Y>> Ghost4_X>>Ghost4_Y>> Ghost5_X>>Ghost5_Y
        >> Ghost6_X>>Ghost6_Y>>Ghost1_state>>Ghost2_state>>Ghost3_state>>Ghost4_state>>Ghost5_state>>Ghost6_state>>P1_HP>>P2_HP>>P1_Score>>P2_Score;    

if(!stream->commitTransaction()){
    return;
}
delete stream;
qDebug()<<"P1_X"<<P1_X<<" P1_Y: "<<P1_Y<<"P1 score:"<<P1_Score <<endl;
qDebug()<<"P2_X"<<P2_X<<" P1_Y: "<<P2_Y<<"P1 score:"<<P2_Score <<endl;
emit DataReceived();  }
```

Sender (server side):

```
void ServerTcpHelper::SendPacket(){

qDebug()<<"sending.."<<endl;
stream=new QDataStream (&this->Data,QIODevice::OpenModeFlag::ReadWrite);
*stream<<P1_X<<P1_Y<<P2_X<<P2_Y<<Ghost1_X<<Ghost1_Y<<Ghost2_X<<Ghost2_Y<< Ghost3_X<<Ghost3_Y<< Ghost4_X<<Ghost4_Y<< Ghost5_X<<Ghost5_Y
      << Ghost6_X<<Ghost6_Y<<Ghost1_state<<Ghost2_state<<Ghost3_state<<Ghost4_state<<Ghost5_state<<Ghost6_state<<P1_HP<<P2_HP<<P1_Score<<P2_Score;
if(P1socket->state()==QTcpSocket::ConnectedState){
    P1socket->write(Data);
    P1socket->waitForBytesWritten(50);
}
if(P2socket->state()==QTcpSocket::ConnectedState){
    P2socket->write(Data);
    P2socket->waitForBytesWritten(50);
}
delete stream;
Data.clear();}
```

The debug stream from receiver shows valid values 
(eg. P1_X: 960 P1_Y:40 P1_Score: 48) but those values don't seem to last, they get zeroed when UnpackData is finished (I mean - when i try to get them out with Getters of ClientTCPHelper in main program).

Comment: Your implementation of `ClientTcpHelper::UnpackData` seems to assume that all data is available.  `TCP` doesn't work like that -- it's simply a byte stream.  You need to buffer the incoming data until you know a complete transaction can be carried out and *then* deserialize it through a `QDataStream`.  On a side note, there is absolutely no reason to allocate the `QDataStream` on the heap here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
It seems that allocating stream on heap was the problem. Using 
` stream->startTransaction(); `  though takes care of fragmented data.
all wroks fine now, thanks again!